# How to end a loop using ALT key in 8086

Tags: assembly, decimal, cpu-registers, x86-16

my teacher asked me to write a program which take maximum 100 numbers and stop whenever user press the ALT key.
and Also goes to next number whenever the user press ENTER key. 
 But i can figure out how to do that,since The ALT key has no ASCII code and i have to use one of the services of  `INT 16H` .
But how can i use that ?
i wrote a code that i think might be correct,but the respond is that the user should press the key Twice .
please help how to solve it ?

### here is my code :

> .....
>   next_digit:
>
> ```
> mov AH,07H
> int 21H
> CMP AL,0DH                     ; check if the user pressed ENTER !
> JNE check_digit                ; goes to calculate the number !
> CMP BH,6                       ;if nothing entered !
> JE next_digit
> ;***************************************************
> ;*    I think here is the place to put this code : *
> ;*                                                 *
> ;*    mov AH,02H                                   *
> ;*    int 16H                                      *
> ;*    CMP AL,00001000B                             *
> ;*    JE END                                       *
> ;***************************************************
> ....
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a complete program (in NASM syntax) that reads keystrokes, echoes them to the console, and exits as soon as you press Alt:

```
org 0x100

main:
    mov ah,1
    int 16h     ; CHECK FOR KEYSTROKE
    jnz got_keystroke

    mov ah,2
    int 16h     ; GET SHIFT FLAGS
    test al,8   ; Alt
    jnz done
    jmp main

got_keystroke:
    mov ah,0    ; GET KEYSTROKE (to remove it from the buffer)
    int 16h

    ; Echo to screen
    mov dl,al
    mov ah,2
    int 21h
    jmp main

done:    
int 20h   ; Exit to DOS
```

Comment: But another question : how we can find out if the user pressed the number " 8 " or not,seems the program defines ALt and 8 as equal !

Comment: 8 and '8' are not the same. To check if the 8-key was pressed, you do something like `cmp al,'8'` / `je eight_pressed` where the "Echo to screen" code currently is.

Comment: Sorry to bother,im stuck in finishing this code,how to write a program to take maximum 6 digits numbers and find the average ?

Comment: That's a different question, and should be posted as a new question. But you should make an attempt to solve it yourself first. Think about how you'd do that in another langauge, then translate that into x86 assembly.